# I can't update articles on joomla website

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a joomla 3.0 website that i'm having challenges when i try to update articles it redirects to the websites home page. Surprisingly i not experiencing the problem on my localhost. Here is my .htaccess file

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

#RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: More info needed about your issue. Posting your htaccess doesn't help, to not mention that it doesn't seem to be caused by your htaccess. Also you may be luckier in getting a better answer at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/, but in any case provide as much information as possible about your issue.

Comment: the issue occurs when editing an article, when i click on save button it automatically redirects to the home page without saving my changes

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite engine is tunred off:

```
#RewriteEngine On
```

Just turn it on:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

And after that clear all caches (joomla and browser).